# SQLCODE: -420, SQLSTATE: 22018, SQLERRMC: BIGINT

Tags: db2

[Running DB2 UDB version 9] Why does this SQL statement work

```
SELECT 
       CASE
       WHEN A.DAILYDOWNLOADSIZE is null THEN 0
    else bigint(A.DAILYDOWNLOADSIZE)
       END "DAILYDOWNLOADSIZE",
       CASE
       WHEN A.DAILYDOWNLOADTIME is null THEN 0
    else bigint(A.DAILYDOWNLOADTIME)
       END "DAILYDOWNLOADTIME"
FROM 
EDMPROD.MQT_STB_FACTS A
```

...when this one does not

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
bigint(A.CAMID) AS "CAMID",
bigint(A.RID) AS "RID",
A.SOFTWAREVERSION,
A.MODELNUMBER,
A.MANUFACTURERID,
A.MODDATE,
A.POSTTIME,
A.DELIVERYMETHOD,
bigint(A.UPTIME )  AS "UPTIME",
bigint(A.NUMBEROFRESETSSINCELASTSWDL )  AS "NUMBEROFRESETSSINCELASTSWDL",
bigint(A.NUMBEROFSEARCHSIGNALOSDTUNER1 ) AS "NUMBEROFSEARCHSIGNALOSDTUNER1",
bigint(A.NUMBEROFSEARCHSIGNALOSDTUNER2 ) AS "NUMBEROFSEARCHSIGNALOSDTUNER2",
bigint(A.NUMBEROFUSERDISKREFORMATS ) AS "NUMBEROFUSERDISKREFORMATS",
bigint(A.NUMBEROFSYSTEMDISKREFORMATS ) AS "NUMBEROFSYSTEMDISKREFORMATS",
bigint(A.NUMBEROFRECOVEREDDISKERRORS ) AS "NUMBEROFRECOVEREDDISKERRORS",
IPINFO,
       CASE
       WHEN A.DAILYDOWNLOADSIZE is null THEN 0
    else bigint(A.DAILYDOWNLOADSIZE)
       END "DAILYDOWNLOADSIZE",
       CASE
       WHEN A.DAILYDOWNLOADTIME is null THEN 0
    else bigint(A.DAILYDOWNLOADTIME)
       END "DAILYDOWNLOADTIME",
bigint(A.TOTALNUMBEROFDOWNLOADSSTARTED ) AS "TOTALNUMBEROFDOWNLOADSSTARTED",
bigint(A.TOTALNUMOFCOMPLETEDDLS ) AS "TOTALNUMOFCOMPLETEDDLS",
CURRENT_DATE AS "LOAD_DATE"
FROM 
EDMPROD.MQT_STB_FACTS A
```

I get an error **SQL0420N  Invalid character found in a character string argument of the 
function "BIGINT".  SQLSTATE=22018**.

By troubleshooting the query, I confirm the culprits are the two columns DAILYDOWNLOADSIZE and DAILYDOWNLOADTIME. Both must be casted from character(15) to bigint.

What is the second SQL statement not working???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was losing my mind over this so I made a simple change in my staging table (EDMPROD.MQT_STB_FACTS).

Instead of typing the columns as characters and then casting them as bigint, I dropped and recreated my table with the datatypes set to BIGINT(8).

I removed the castings from my SQL statement and the error went away.

Go figure..........

Comment: This is not an elegant solution. I have the same issue I can't fix it. Did you by any chance find another way ?

Comment: Using the proper data type in the database is what I would consider elegant so we'll have to disagree on that. Using the proper data types is a good practice.