# Alternative for regexp_replace for BIGINT

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

I'm quite new at programming with Oracle and DB2 and have a question. I need to mask a field that has a BIGING as datatype. But when i tried to execute a query with regexp_replace, i have this error line SQLCODE=-420, SQLSTATE=22018.
Is there a alternative for a regexp_replace for BIGING.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you show the query please?

Comment: It looks like there is a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023861/sqlcode-420-sqlstate-22018-sqlerrmc-bigint

Comment: @HRK he has already a bigint

Comment: Please include the full error message you're getting. Oracle and DB2 are completely different database products. Also - Oracle does not have a BIGINT data type (unless you're using some variety of user-defined type). Which database product are you using?

Comment: Please include your code... or at least a example of the original data  and the masked data you want returned.

Comment: Here is the part of the code update Person.T_PERSON 
set PK_PERSON = REGEXP_REPLACE(PK_PERSON, '[0-9]', '*')
where PK_PERSON in ('117888');

Comment: and the error An invalid character was found in a string argument of the function "BIGINT".SQLCODE=-420, SQLSTATE=22018, DRIVER=4.31.10 SQL Code: -420, SQL State: 22018

Comment: @michNik You should understand that you try to set a string constant (all `*`s which can't be converted to BIGINT) to a BIGINT column, and it's impossible. Can you explain the desired masking algorithm in words?

Answer (score 0):

You can 'mask' integers by replace all digits except first and last by zeroes using next code (Oracle):

```
select 
    N, -- source number
    FLOOR(N/POWER(10, FLOOR(LOG(10, N)))) * POWER(10, FLOOR(LOG(10, N))) + MOD(N, 10) MASKED
from a;
```

[run sql online](https://sqlize.online/sql/oracle21/415cde94a71fccee47b2634eac215f7c/)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the platform and version of Db2, you might consider using [`CREATE MASK`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-mask) if available.  That would ensure the data is always masked without needing to do it in every application.

A quick search seems to indicate the Oracle also has similar support but they call it [redaction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/asoag/introduction-to-oracle-data-redaction.html#GUID-82EA9712-387C-4D3A-BB72-F64A707C67CA).  Masking in oracle seems to be tied into [subsetting](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dmksb/intro.html#GUID-24B241AF-F77F-46ED-BEAE-3919BF1BBD80) and exporting data from production to DEV/TEST.

Do you really need a solution for both RDBMs?

And if you really want to roll your own, you need to provide some examples of the masked value you want returned.

**EDIT**

> Here is a part of the code. PK_PERSON has BIGINT as datatype. update
> Person.T_PERSON set PK_PERSON = REGEXP_REPLACE(PK_PERSON, '[0-9]',
> '*') where PK_PERSON in ('117888')

That's not going to work, you can't set a BIGINT column to a string.  That's also not how masking works.  Masking generally refers to a process that happens when the data is read out of the DB.

Comment: Hi, i need to mask a few rows, not a whole column. And the DB is Db2. Here is a part of the code. PK_PERSON has BIGINT as datatype. update Person.T_PERSON set PK_PERSON = REGEXP_REPLACE(PK_PERSON, '[0-9]', '*') where PK_PERSON in ('117888');